# simple-jwt isn't authenticating my login attempts

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I've created a custom user model that allows users to log in with their email and phone number. I tried implementing simple jwt authentication but I keep getting the error:

```
{
    "detail": "No active account found with the given credentials"
}
```

Note that I've attempted logging in using only active accounts and super user accounts created both before and after attempting to login

This is in my models.py file

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, name, email, phone_number, password, **other_fields):
        if not phone_number:
            raise ValueError('You must provide a phone number')
        user = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, name=name, phone_number=phone_number, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
    
    def create_superuser(self, name, email, phone_number, password, **other_fields):
        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must be assigned to is_staff = True')
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser = True')
        return self.create_user(name, email, phone_number, password, **other_fields)


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS =['name', 'email']



    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My backends.py file to allow users to log in with their  email

```
class EmailOrPhoneNumberBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            try:
                user = UserModel.objects.get(phone_number=username)
            except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
                return None

        if user.check_password(password):
            return user

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            return UserModel.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

And my settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "users.apps.UsersConfig",
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'django_rest_passwordreset',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'users.backends.EmailOrPhoneNumberBackend',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',

    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES' :[
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ]
    
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'phone_number',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'id',
    'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',
}
```

I've seen this question get asked so many times and I've tried everything but they all haven't worked for me. Please help

Comment: consider is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False) should not be True?

Comment: I know that's not the problem because I manually activated some accounts and tried logging in with them but nothing changed. I'm lost